# Wifi Issues when using ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04

I built my new PC just this week, and while using it i had no issues with my WiFi but now it breaks down unable to connect to my WiFi and when I do the speed is so bad that i can't even watch a video on YouTube in 144p  whereas with same connection on my smartphone it works fine without any issues even on 720p, So, i followed [this tutorial](https://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/) and it worked fine for 2-3 days and it is now back to same issues i feel like i may have done something completely wrong as i followed few tutorials. My motherboard is b550 msi gaming carbon wifi(antenna one), i went to [this link](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/MPG-B550-GAMING-CARBON-WIFI/Specification) and it showed that I have intel wifi 6 wireless drivers. I disabled power for wifi too but that doesn't work that well as continuous fluctuations happen. Please help, as this is stopping me from watching videos regarding course works.

Comment: Hi there. This is probably a duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/search?q=intel+ax200+slow 
For example: https://askubuntu.com/a/1216017/853283

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intel AX200 Wifi not working after update to Kubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240535/intel-ax200-wifi-not-working-after-update-to-kubuntu-20-04)

Comment: @ThankYee I tried both of the solution, it didn't help, so what I did was reinstalled ubuntu and it worked fine then. Thank you for the response